# Как вывести кол-во зарегистрированных пользователей на сайте? PHP+SQL

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

И как вывести с какими либо условиями или ограничениями?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый вечер.
Запрос может выглядеть так

```
$results = $mysqli->query('SELECT COUNT(`username`) FROM `users`');

$rows = $results->fetch_array();

print_r($rows);

$mysqli->close();
```

С какими ограничениями Вы хотите вывести записи?
Добавить условие выборки в запрос можно при помощи **where**

```
'SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  `user_count`  FROM `user` WHERE `status` = 1'
```

Comment: Добрый. Да что-то типо такого
'SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  `user_count`  FROM `user` WHERE `status` = 1'
потом просто echo $user_count; ?